# Is seq from PersistentVector faster than seq from PersistentList when we pushed elements to the end?

Tags: clojure

Is seq from PersistentVector

```clj
(seq [1 2 3])
```

faster than seq from PersistentList

```clj
(seq '(1 2 3))
```

when we pushed elements into them?
Are their performance equal except type?

I tried to find answer in the internet but unfortunately didn't find any about comparison of

```clj
(seq [1 2 3])
```

and

```clj
(seq `(1 2 3))
```

Comment: Whatever the answer is, you shouldn't rely on it. More often than not, it's impossible to give a clear answer in similar cases when it comes to JVM. But also, what exactly do you mean by "push elements into them"? Can you add some specific code?

Comment: @EugenePakhomov Thank you. In general, `(conj (seq [1 2 3]))` will be faster than `(conj (seq '(1 2 3)))`?

Comment: You could measure your usecase with Criterium. Also appending on the end is the "natural" conj for a vector. What do you mean by "pusing elements to the end"? What is the actual problem you are solving?

Comment: @cfrick I'm just  wondering in theory whether it's under the hood a single data structure or not

Comment: Then why not ask this? What if they have the same performance characteristics, but are different data structures?

Comment: @cfrick I think, if it would different data structures, then it would be different performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `[1 2 3]` is [PersistentVector](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java) and the type of `(1 2 3)` is [clojure.lang.Cons](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Cons.java).

Calling [seq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/seq) just calls to [RT.seq](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L531), which has a shortcut if the collection is an instance of `ASeq`, otherwise calls to `RT.seqFrom` to create a new sequence. Since `Cons` is already an instance of `ASeq`, it will just return the argument without creating a new seq object.

```
user=> (def abc `(1 2 3))
#'user/abc

user=> (identical? abc (seq abc))
true
```

To summarize, calling `(seq '(1 2 3))` should be slightly faster than calling `(seq [1 2 3])`, because in the former case, it just returns the argument directly, but in the latter case, a new `ChunkedSeq` is allocated for the vector.

However, please note that the difference might be still negligible in production environments and there are many other factors to consider when writing code for really low latency applications.

Comment: Thank you. But in general, `(conj (seq [1 2 3]))` will be faster than `(conj (seq '(1 2 3)))`?

Comment: Both `conj` operations should have `O(1)` runtime complexity and both create only a small new object containing the head and tail elements, so the difference is negligible and therefore difficult to measure.

Comment: `(conj x)` is basically `(identity x)` - why do you care about its performance?

Comment: @cfrick I'm just wondering in theory whether it's under the hood a single data structure or not